# *display css hack?

Tags: css

I recently started to work on a client's website. In the css it has a lot of references to "*display" usually in combination with "zoom" like below.

Is this a known hack? What is the expected behaviour?

```
header #mybar ul.right {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hack to target IE7 it will not be picked up by modern browsers such as Firefox or Chrome, IE>8.  So for instance, IE7 would display the element as inline, while others would ignore this style and display the `UL` appropriately as a block level element.